# How to link mysql library to Qt compiled statically?

Tags: mysql, qt

I have trouble lately with linking mysql library to Qt Static. Here what I had done so far:

1) Compile QT 5.4.2 static

2) Compile mysql plugin driver

3) After that I copy .dll and .a file to both static and non-static QT's plugin folder

4) For non-static QT, everything go normal, but I can't compile project with static QT

In my .pro file

```
LIBS += -LC:/Qt/Static/5.3.1/plugins/sqldrivers -lqsqlmysql

QTPLUGIN += libqsqlmysql
```

Error : `:-1: error: cannot find -llibqsqlmysql`

I also get a warning on .pro file :

```
Project WARNING: Plugin class name could not be determined for libqsqlmysql plugin.
```

Please help

Comment: Whats the error message? _"can't compile"_ could mean anything.

Comment: I'm sorry. Update in question

Comment: Meybe this link helps you http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-18153.html

Comment: I already read this topic, but it very vague for a newbie for me, also looks like he use Linux Platform (  ./configure )

What is this command ./configure -static -plugin-sql-mysql  do at first place?